# Как правильно записать данные в .txt файл в Python 3.x

Tags: python-3.x, vkontakte-api

Написал код для перевода vk id (числовая запись, пример: 15155637) из файла members_club_list5.txt  в формат @15155637 (Ямиль). Как выводимый результат мне сохранить в файл users.txt?

```
import requests
chel = open('users.txt', 'w')
us_id = open('members_club_list5.txt', 'r')

for i in us_id: 
    r = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get',params={'user_ids':i,'fields':'followers_count'})
    response=r.json() 
    d=response['response'][0]['uid']
    f=response['response'][0]['first_name']

    print(f'@id{d} ({f})') #Вместо этого, сделать запись в файл

us_id.close()
chel.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [1]: chel = 'users.txt'
   ...: us_id ='members_club_list5.txt'
   ...:

In [5]: with open(chel, 'w') as chelFile, open(us_id) as usersFile:
   ...:     for i in usersFile.readlines():
   ...:         r = requests.get('https://api.vk.com/method/users.get',params={'user_ids':i,'fields':'followers_count'})
   ...:         response=r.json()
   ...:         d=response['response'][0]['uid']
   ...:         f=response['response'][0]['first_name']
   ...:         chelFile.write(f'@id{d} ({f})\n')
   ...:
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, помогло, но для желающих применить данный ответ добавлю, что для корректной записи результатов добавьте строку кодировки символов     with open(chel, 'w', encoding = "utf8") as chelFile, open(us_id) as usersFile:

Comment: @Yamil для взаимодействия с VK API используйте уже готовые библиотеки. А не дёргайте реквестами. Например: https://habrahabr.ru/post/319178/